Professor and two students
A mathematics professor has two bright students, Patty and Sofie. The professor invents a puzzle to test their skills, choosing two natural numbers larger than 3. The professor tells Patty the product and Sofie the sum of the two numbers, then asks the two of them alternatingly and repeatedly whether they know what the numbers are, receiving the following answers:

Patty: I don't know what the numbers are.

Sofie: I don't know what the numbers are.

Patty: I don't know what the numbers are.

Sofie: I don't know what the numbers are.

Patty: I don't know what the numbers are.

Sofie: I don't know what the numbers are.

Patty: Now I know what the numbers are!

Sofie: Now I also know what the numbers are!


Question: What are the two numbers chosen by the professor?
Note: This puzzle was designed by me, many years ago. It is based on a similar (but simpler) puzzle by Martin Gardner (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_and_Product_Puzzle), published decades ago. It is difficult to solve, and you will undoubtedly need pen and paper.

Welcome to PSE. Is brute force allowed for this question. (If not, add the no-computers tag) :-)

Also, are we allowed to read the Martin Gardner puzzle solution or is that "cheating"

You are free to use the Martin Gardner puzzle. Brute force is allowed, but I am afraid it will not help you much.

Just for curiosity, there is no upper limit for the sum and there is a unique solution?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

To clarify: are the numbers chosen by the professor distinct?

Can you give a hint on the magnitude of the solution?

There is no upper limit for the sum or the product. There is a unique solution. The two numbers need not be distinct, so for example (5,5) could me the solution but also (8,9).  The solution consists of two relatively small numbers. One can check that a pair of larger numbers, say (56, 99), can not work.


 Wrote a octave/matlab script:   (try it online).
 It returns the following answer: sum=$16$, product=$48$, leading to the pair of numbers $(4,12)$.


 Idea of the program: each pair of sum-product $(a+b,ab)$ corresponds to at most one pair of numbers $(a,b)$.
 First, all possible pairs of sum-product up to a maximal sum of $100$ are produced: this fills a matrix indexed by (sum,product) with 0s/1s.
 In each step, columns/rows are zeroed that contain less than two non-zero entries (for the do-not-know steps) or not exactly one entry (for the I-know steps).


 No proof: the program has a restriction on the maximal sum of numbers, so it is not clear why there are no other (much larger) solutions.


From your last paragraph, it looks like you are allowing 3 as a possible number. The question states "larger than 3" which makes a difference to the solution space.

Thanks for pointing this out! indeed, this is the error that I was looking for all the time.

Congratulations ! You have solved the puzzle and found the correct answer.

Here is my own answer, which is based on straightforward mathematics and logic.
From Patty's first "I don't know what the numbers are" we can conclude that there are two or more solutions corresponding to the product she was given by the professor. This eliminates many possible pairs. The remaining ones have as product 36, 40, 48, 56, 60, 64, 70, 72, 80, 84, 88, 90.....
Now use pen and paper to make a tabel of values for the sum as a function of the above products. We see that there are only two values for P for which S has only one value. Namely P = 36, S = 12 corresponding to the pair (6,6). And P = 56, S = 15 corresponding to the pair (7,8). From Sofie's answer we now know that these pairs are not the solution.
Patty will now know the solution if she has P = 36, corresponding to (4,9). Or P = 56, corresponding to (4,14). Since she does not know the solution, these two pairs are eliminated.
Sofie can only know the solution if she has S = 13, corresponding to (5,8). Because if she has S = 18, she can draw no conclusion since there are still two possible pairs matching, namely (6,12) and (8,10).
Patty next signals that she does not have product 40, corresponding to (4,10).
Sofie then signals that she does not have sum 14, corresponding to (6,8).
Patty now knows the solution. It must be with product 48, and is therefore the pair (4,12). Sofie comes to the same conclusion.

How would you argue that there are no solutions with very large numbers, say with 10 digits?

For S is large, there are always many pairs of possible solutions. You can combine a small number with a large even number. For example S = 31, then (5,26), (7,24), (9, 22) are good pairs. That is because you can take a factor 2 out of the even number and multiply it with the small number. Giving: (10,13), (14,12), (18, 11). So S = 31 can never work, and similarly for all other large values of S.
